# What is the purpose of libstdc++-dbg?

Tags: package-management, compiling, debugging

The **Synaptics package manager** says that:

> This package contains the shared library of libstdc++ compiled with
>   debugging symbols.

But I can successfully print the contents of `std` members in the debugger without having this library. This is probably because most of them are templated, so the compiler can see the entire source code. But what good is a compiled library where the user cannot see the source code?

I am really confused. Please, could you explain?